# His insistence "to see" OR "that he see" something?

Tags: subjunctives

I know that the verb "to insist" has to be followed by a subjunctive in sentences like "I insist that he do it.". However, I do not know if the noun "insistence" behave in the same way. 
I am not sure which of the two choices listed below is the correct one.

1) His continuous insistence, **to see** the new apparatus, was quite annoying.

2) His continuous insistence, **that he see** the new apparatus, was quite annoying.

Comment: One frequently *insists on* something, and in the examples above I'd opt for *his continuous insistence on seeing...* as the most idiomatic construction. But if  I had to choose between your examples, I'd choose the second.

Comment: So, "on seeing" is the correct version.

Comment: Initial point: I would replace "continuous" with "continued" or "continual" Yes, the noun "insistence" can take subjunctive clausal complements. Your example 1) is not a subjunctive though, since "see" is part of the _to-_ infinitival, not the subjunctive infinitival. Ex 2) is a genuine subjunctive and is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence #1 isn't grammatical.  You don't use a to-infinitive after insist/insistence.  You insist on something/doing something. So the sentence should be as follows:

His continuous insistence on seeing the new apparatus was quite annoying.

The sentence #2 as follows is correct:

His continuous insistence that he see the new apparatus was quite annoying.

In BrE, you can also say:

His continuous insistence that he should see the new apparatus was quite anoying.

Answer (score 0):

Both of your sentences are correct and would be understood to have the same meaning

> His continuous insistence, **to see** the new apparatus, was quite annoying.
>   His continuous insistence, **that he see** the new apparatus, was quite annoying.

You could also use

> His *continual* insistence